# npx create-react-app my-app fails because of vulnerability

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, npx

`npm install` fails. full output:

After this my `npx` **stop working**.... What should I do?

```
Creating a new React app in D:\New folder\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

core-js@2.6.11 postinstall D:\New folder\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


core-js@3.6.5 postinstall D:\New folder\my-app\node_modules\core-js
node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall D:\New folder\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react@16.13.1     
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
added 1602 packages from 750 contributors and audited 1606 packages in 107.248s

63 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"? Can you call `npx` at all after this?

Comment: I don't see any error message here

Comment: After npm audit fix , my terminal stop working

Comment: I mean in the end their should be happy hacking and whole download will be complited. But in my case it download to this npm audit fix and just stop working.

Comment: After looking online, it seems like there is a problem with node.js `v12.6.2`, x64, which causes the problem you are facing. If you run `node -v`, what do you get? Is it `v12.6.2`? I would suggest updating to the latest version of node.js by going to [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) and downloading the latest version, which (currently) is either `v12.8.3` for the long term support version, or `14.6.0` for the current version. Either one should be fine.